# Change diff format/output in Ansible? External diff command?

Tags: ansible

when using `--diff` in Ansible (here v2.11), it shows me a diff of changes. I would like to change the output formatting of that. Is it possible, in ansible, to tell it to use an external command to generate the diff string/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying Ansible's diff method requires code changes.

Values for the [`diff` dict](https://blog.networktocode.com/post/generating-diff-with-ansible/) returned is the responsibility of each module. Ether `before` and `after` keys with a full text representation of the states, `lineinfile` is an example of this. Or a `prepared` key where the module does the diff itself, such as what the `git` module does.

There is no general purpose method of changing the prepared diff method for modules, to diffutils scripts or Python difflib or whatever. Consider writing common diff wrappers as `module_utils` code if you wish for this to be an option everywhere.

Callback plugins do something with this diff output, the default callback prints diffs. Nearly all callbacks that reference diffs use [CallbackBase._get_diff](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.11/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.py#L168),  which in turn makes use of Python difflib to compare `before` and `after`.

To change stdout, write a callback plugin, probably subclassing the default plugin and replacing method `v2_on_file_diff`.

---

Ansible diff to me is for human consumption, colorized and pretty printed inside lots of other output. Machine parsable diffs might be easier to get from an over time database, such as your Ansible playbooks in version control.